# Converting data audio to mp3 (or ogg)

Tags: blob, mp3, html5-audio, mediarecorder, getusermedia

I want to convert data audio that I have as a `Blob` coming from my microphone, to another (less space taking) format.

And I found [this project](https://github.com/sb2702/audioRecord.js) on GitHub, it does something quite close what I want, but the problem is that I get my audio data through:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
then
rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
rec.ondataavailable = e => {
    .......
    audioChunks.push(e.data);
    if (rec.state == "inactive") {
        let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'});
        .....
```

while the project I found handles data audio in a different way:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, function(stream) {
      callback(new RecorderObject(audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream), cfg));
}, function(e) {
      console.log("An error occurred"); //Null if something goes wrong
      callback(null);
});
```

As a result it seems complicated to use what I see in the GitHub project for my own one.
I would be glad if someone mastering the subject an possibly knowing the project I am referring to could tell me if there is some way I can adapt what is done it the project to fit my own needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is already doing what you want.  The MediaRecorder includes codec support.

The line:

```
let blob = new Blob(audioChunks, {type: 'audio/x-mpeg-3'});
```

should be:

```
let blob = new Blob(audioChunks, {type: rec.mimeType});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/mimeType

Also note that for older browsers, the `mimeType` property may not be present.  For those, simply initialize the MediaRecorder with the same type.

```
new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: 'audio/webm'})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/MediaRecorder

The second example is for recording PCM data with the Web Audio API... a technique that is no longer necessary, particularly that the MediaRecorder supports PCM in WebM now.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that is a good news since the first example is my own code. Then how do I extract the mp3 (or ogg) file from that point, because this is my current problem.

Comment: You've already done it... it's in that blob.  (The `type` is wrong... try audio/webm, but yeah that's the gist.)

Comment: Oh. You mean this "let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'});" already gives me mp3 (or ogg) data? Then I need to double check.

Comment: Well, after checking; that does not seem to be .mp3 or .ogg. I still need to change something to make it work. You mentioned "the type is wrong", that means I must change the parameter "{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'}" ?

Comment: By using "{type:'audio/ogg; codecs=opus'}"; I finally have something working. I edited your answer and accepted it.

Comment: @Michel Well, that's not really correct.  You need to match what you pass in to MediaRecorder.

Comment: OK. I know that it now works. Please tell me how to write the code correctly, then it will be perfect. I have zero experience with this, I can easily believe that what I do is not the correct thing.

Comment: Yes it still works like that too. But I am not mentioning ogg/opus anywhere anymore. Though the result still seems to be "Ogg data, Opus audio". Why is that? Does ogg/opus just happens to be some kind of default?

Comment: @Michel Correct.  The default is browser-specific, but Opus in Ogg is common.